# SVPullToRefresh stick

Tags: ios, objective-c, pull-to-refresh

I searched the internet but to no avail. The SVPullToRefresh stick if I run code:

```
[table.pullToRefreshView startAnimating];
[table.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];
```

[image]

Somewhere in my code load data from cache, and this method calls almost consistently. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update/add the last version of SVPullToRefresh  to your project ? It seems that some people have this issue

> I'm running into an issue where the pull to refresh view doesn't always hide cleanly after calling stopAnimating. I haven't been able to nail down exactly what conditions it occurs under, aside that it appears somewhat "random" in my use.

[Pull to refresh view doesn't always hide cleanly](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh/issues/131)

**Solution :**

> reverting the commit

Comment: How can I revert commit in CocoaPods?

Comment: You have to install it manually, see the documentation on https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh, or you have to wait for a updated pods release of SVPullToRefresh. The issue has been fix 2 months ago and the last release of SVPullToRefresh on CocoaPods was 6 months ago. Maybe ask them to update the pods ?